# How to get Child site option value

Tags: json, wordpress

I am trying to get child site option value for individual site but return false value from site . i did try get_site_option , get_option and get_blog_option also but it's not work my code is

```
$sites = function_exists('wp_get_sites')? wp_get_sites(array('limit'=>9999)) : get_blog_list(0,'all');
$response=array();
$i= 0 ;
foreach( $sites as $site ) {
if( $site['blog_id'] != '' ) {

//$options = (is_multisite()) ? get_site_option($this->option_name) : get_option($this->option_name);

echo "test".get_blog_option($site['blog_id'] , 'wp_31_start_date');
switch_to_blog( $site['blog_id'] );
echo $value = get_site_option( 'wp_31_start_date' );
echo $value1 = get_option( 'wp_31_start_date' );
restore_current_blog();  

$title  =   get_blog_details($site['blog_id'])->blogname;
$url    =   is_subdomain_install() ? "$site[domain]" : "$site[domain]$site[path]";

// Response of sucess
$response['allsites'][$i]['ID']     =   $site['blog_id'];
$response['allsites'][$i]['name']   =   substr( $title,0,30 );
$response['allsites'][$i]['url']    =   esc_url( get_home_url( $site['blog_id'], '/' ) );
//$response['allsites'][$i]['status']   =   'Site '.$site['blog_id'].' was updated '.get_blog_status( $site['blog_id'], $preference );
}
```

Comment: See these links 

[link 1](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181219/whats-the-difference-between-get-site-option-and-get-blog-option) and [link2](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155711/differences-between-behavior-get-option-vs-get-site-option-in-multisite)

Comment: i did try this also you can see into code

Comment: have you checked in database ? what is the option value in DB also verify in DB that your key is correct.

Comment: form clone my child site wp_31_options and into this site i did store wp_31_start_date as option and i am trying to get this option value from table but it's return false value. option value is "31-03-2016"

Comment: @noman thank you link given by it's useful for me